# What is the 5e wizard equivalent of the Still Spell and Silent Spell feats from 3.5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, metamagic

I'm planning on making an illusionist wizard who studies magic so he can put on light shows and have dramatic illusory monsters scare the crowds (think Gandalf's fireworks show from the first Lord of the Rings movie). However, one of the biggest downsides of spellcasting is the obvious chanting and gesticulation required, which makes it a little to obvious that wizard-work is happening. I'd like a little more subtle approach.

In 3.5e, there were the Still Spell and Silent Spell feats, which let you cast spells without somatic and verbal components (respectively) at the cost of using a higher spell slot. However, I can't find an equivalent feat for either of these in 5e (I only have the PHB). I see that sorcerers get the Subtle Magic metamagic class ability, but that doesn't apply to me since I'm playing a wizard. Does something similar to these feats exist in 5th edition for the wizard class?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### First: There isn't an equivalent.

Wizards cannot, by Rules-as-Written, get Metamagic. They just don't have access.

**But, don't worry, there's a few things you might be able to do.**

---

### 1. Three Sorcerer levels

Taking Three levels in Sorcerer (provided your DM allows you to Multiclass) grants you access to the *Subtle Spell* metamagic. You'll have three points to spend (so three times per day) and can be subtle with spells.

> **Subtle Spell**
> When you cast a spell, you can spend 1 sorcery point to cast it without any somatic or verbal components

### 2. Just play a Sorcerer

Sorcerers and Wizards aren't ALL that different at a mechanical level. Depending on exactly what you're trying to achieve with the character, there's little reason (if any) that you couldn't just play a sorcerer that is old, robed, has a righteous beard, and likes to hang out with halflings.

### 3. Use the Metamagic Adept feat from TCE

I'd originally suggested a custom feat, but WotC has made their own that's a little better.

You gain 2 metamagic options and 2 metamagic points that recharge on a long rest.

### 4. Custom Spell <sup>(credit Kamil Drakari)</sup>

Work with the DM to create "new spells" that are existing spells but without verbal/somatic components (probably at higher level than the original version). That would keeps Sorcerers as "flexible casters who can modify spells on-the-fly" while a wizard can get the same effect but needs to prepare for it ahead of time.